# Are there any softwares which help in simulating different experiments regarding flight of aircrafts on different terrestrial planets of solar system?

Tags: earth, planetary-science, software

I have a few experiments on aircrafts whose results I am aware of if performed on the earth's surface. However, I am searching for software(s) that can help simulate the same or other experiments on other terrestrial planets of the solar system too. Is/are there any such software(s) that can help me in this process?

Comment: @StephenG-OnStrike I have made the edits in the question. Pardon me for not being case-specific.

Comment: @notovny my question is more related to flight of aircrafts on different planets especially terrestrial ones.

Comment: @DhruvNayak As long as your question is clear, and there's some evidence of research (just add a link or two, maybe to the helicopter that's flying on Mars to indicate that aviation is already happening now on other worlds) then Aviation SE is the better place for your question - they really do handle edge cases well as long as the quality of the question is good. Since an answer has already been posted, you can't delete and repost now. Instead, it is possible that the question will be closed then possibly migrated. That happens all the time, don't worry.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the flying of an aircraft on Mars, Earth or anywhere else is not itself Astronomy. However, luckily this is on-topic in [Space Exploration SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/) and [Aviation SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/) as well.

Comment: @uhoh oh! I see. Thank you for guiding me _/\_

Comment: You might find this interesting:  https://what-if.xkcd.com/30/

Answer (score 2):

The X-Plane software definitely works.

https://www.x-plane.com/adventures/mars.html

https://forums.x-plane.org/index.php?/forums/topic/138397-huh-x-plane-lets-you-fly-on-mars/

Comment: Is it free, or at least cheap, or expensive? If it costs money, is there at least a temporary, limited demo version license?